# How can I write to a file in Android's internal storage using opencsv?

Tags: android, opencsv

I have a helper class which I need to process data for my application.

I have set it up so it reads the file from a URL.  The reading itself works but I am having difficulty writing this file to the app's internal storage.

As per the Android tutorial I have used a FileOutputStream to write the file.  However, I am finding it difficult finding a solution to write the FileOutputStream and resolving it with the CSVWriter constructor.

The code is very long so I will post a gist if you need more information about what my code is doing but here is the bit which is causing me problems:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file_url.openStream()));
            String test;
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(in, ';');
            FileOutputStream file_out = app_context.openFileOutput(file_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(<What goes here?>, ';');
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4cde37a8614d1c69cc03ec678d36a9d7

Exception thrown with CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(String.valueOf(file_out), ';');:

```
08-19 14:22:30.794 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileOutputStream@dcfb9b3: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
08-19 14:22:30.794 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
08-19 14:22:30.794 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
08-19 14:22:30.794 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
08-19 14:22:30.794 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err:     at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:80)
08-19 14:22:30.794 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err:     at com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph.FileProcessor.processFile(FileProcessor.java:50)
08-19 14:22:30.794 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err:     at com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph.FileProcessor.run(FileProcessor.java:40)
08-19 14:22:30.795 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
08-19 14:22:30.795 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
08-19 14:22:30.795 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
08-19 14:22:30.795 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
08-19 14:22:30.795 29439-30099/com.example.a1003137m.profitgraph W/System.err:  ... 5 more
```

Comment: `<What goes here?>`. Did you try `file_out` ?

Comment: Yeah, it tells me to wrap it with String.valueOf() but it throws an exception.

Comment: And you are not going to tell which one? Not clever! Post the logcat.

Comment: `it tells me to wrap it with String.valueOf()` ?? Who is telling you that?

Comment: `file_url.openStream()`What is `file_url` ? Show code please.

Comment: So during compile time. But what did you do then? Because if you didnt do that your code would not compile and you had no app and no exception.

Comment: To use String.valueOf() is of course a ridiculous hint of Android Studio.

Comment: Since then I have been trying to find a way to have the OpenCSV writer write to a FileOutputStream, as the only constructors available are Writer objects.  I haven't found any which haven't thrown compiler errors.

I suspect I need to wrap it in a writer object or two but I can't find the correct combination.

Comment: `new CSVReader(in, ';');` Now `in` is an `InputStream`. So what would you use with `new CSVWriter( out, ';');` ? Indeed: an `OutputStream`!. Also for the reader you used `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader`. So what are you going to use with the writer? ... Yes!  `BufferedWriter` and `OutputStreamWriter`. Show your code (in your post) and we will see.

Comment: It makes sense to tell what `file_url` is. I asked that already.

Comment: It is an URL pointing to a file which is being read from.

Also your answer was writing about the OutputStreamWriter.  If you want to copy that comment below I will accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new CSVReader(in, ';');` Now `in` is an `InputStream`. So what would you use with `new CSVWriter( out, ';');` ? Indeed: an `OutputStream`!. Also for the reader you used `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader`.

So do something similar: `BufferedWriter` and `OutputStreamWriter`.